# local src file doesn't exist when trying to use expo go

Tags: react-native

So I'm new to React Native Expo and am trying to build a social app. Trying to test my app on my iPhone, I used my camera to scan the QR code provided by the Metro Bundler and tried to open my app on Expo Go. So I have different screens and a js file for each of the screens, and the bundler returns an error says the source code for the screens doesn't exist. It worked fine on a web browser on my computer. Any idea how to solve this? This might be a stupid question. Thanks a lot.

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCEq3.jpg)

Comment: You can check if the file names are in correct case and are at correct path.

Comment: Thanks, but they are correct because it works in the browser mode.